Dynamically find median in Power BI based on two columns?
I got this type of table:




quantity
price




0
1
12


1
2
10


2
3
5


3
1
7



I need to find median price.
But first I need make array with prices:
[12, 10, 10, 5, 5, 5, 7]
So I need make duplicates of price values. And count median for this array.
How to make it in Power BI with DAX statement?

Your sample table is called Test.
Measure = 

MEDIANX(
    GENERATE(
        Test,
        VAR x = GENERATESERIES(1,Test[quantity], 1)
        RETURN x
    ),
    [price]
)



It works, my median is "empty", cause in data to much "NaN" values. =)
